# Setting navigation drawer activity as main activity when app start

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, navigation-drawer

I have made a navigation drawer with six activities but the thing is i want to make one of these six activities as my main activity so that everytime i open the app it will be shown as my main activity

Comment: and what have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: I haven't tried anything i just dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use intent filter in your manifest file to add your preferred activity as a launcher activity.

**Open your manifest file and use intent filter in that activity which you want to make as a launcher activity**

```
<activity android:name=".Your_Activity_Name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```